# Unable to access Jenkins from Oracle virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, jenkins

I have successfully downloaded jenkins on Oracle virtualbox. Services are up and running. However when trying to access the URl. It gives page "site can't be reached"

I am able to ping the server from my local host:

```
Pinging 192.168.2.226 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.2.226: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.2.226: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.2.226: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.2.226: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.2.226:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Please advise about what went wrong. How can I access jenkins url: `https://localhost:8080` or `https://192.168.2.226:8080`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you reach the service from the guest server?
2. output: netstat -tulpn | grep :8080
3. Is there a firewall on the guest server? iptables -L
4. Can you do ssh to 192.168.2.226 ? (if not do -vvv .. superverbose)
5. Portforwarding is so much easier using Vagrant (one line in the Vagrantfile). I encourage you to utilize Vagrant. I am sure there are (tons of) vagrant boxes with Jenkins configured.

Comment: Question 1 being most important. Port forwarding should not be required here.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer using http://localhost:8080 [not https], it can be done using ssh tunnel. Jenkins should be running/listening at port 8080.

You need ssh access to 192.168.2.226[GUEST] from your HOST

For Mac/Linux servers:

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 <USERNAME>@192.168.2.226
```

Then open your browse and try access http://localhost:8080

ssh -L command, forward all request from HOST:8080 to guest:8080

- Guest is 192.168.2.226.
- Host is your server, where virtual box is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the below command it will reset the iptables. Jenkins service should be up and running state.

iptables -F && iptables -t nat -F && iptables -t mangle -F && iptables -X